# Service Accounts not showing in Developers Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my project's Developer Console, Permissions > Service Accounts, I just get the loading spinning blue circle. I want to be able to see the service email addresses and generate keys...

This also happens with other pages, e.g. Logging.

Any advice on how to fix this? I've tried clearing cache & cookies, doing a "cache refresh" with `shift`+refresh; no luck.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: No I didn't try that, but after some length of time things just started working again.

Comment: Perhaps Google had some issue on their end at that time.

Comment: I was perplexed because the same project seemed to be fine on a coworker's machine, so I wonder if using a different browser would've helped. Either way, thanks, @VadimSolovey.

Comment: I'm seeing the same.